# redirect old post type url to new structure url

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

i have one cpt Anime and it has post_type taxonomy with term anime and animation

```
anime(cpt): (site domain)/anime/post title
     |
     |-(tax)Anime
     |-(tax)Animation
```

And my url structure are like: (site domain)/anime/post title
but i wanna this kind of urls:

```
anime
     |
     |-(tax)Anime: (site domain)/anime/post title
     |-(tax)Animation: (site domain)/animation/post title
```

i really don't know how to build it.

after alot of try and error i find my solution:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'events_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function events_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample){

$types=wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'post_types' );
if (( 'animation' == $types[0]->slug )or ( 'comic' == $types[0]->slug )) {
    $post_link = str_replace( array('/anime/','/manga/'), '/'.$types[0]->slug.'/', $post_link );
}
return $post_link;
}



 add_action('init','animation_init');
 function animation_init() {
 global $wp,$wp_rewrite,$wp_query;
 $wp_rewrite->add_rule('^comic/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?post_type=manga&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule('^animation/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?post_type=animes&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
  // Once you get working, remove this next line
  //$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  
 }
```

but now i face a new problem, my old urls still working like:

http://animup.net/anime/the-advantures-of-brer-rabbit/
(should redirect to)
http://animup.net/animation/the-advantures-of-brer-rabbit/

Answer (score 0):

The old permalinks still work because the rewrite rules that support those permalinks still exist. When you register a post type, setting the `rewrite` argument generates the rules to resolve incoming requests. Rather than adding new rules in addition to the originals, just alter the original post type registration.

Comment: i don't wanna redirect all urls, i only wanna redirect posts with animation taxonomy term.